# Is $L(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ a free group factor?

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, free-probability

This is a reference request for something that is likely to be well-known to operator algebraists. I will not, therefore, include the technical definition of free product of finite von Neumann algebras, but instead refer the reader to [Ching - Free products of von Neumann algebras](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-178-00/S0002-9947-1973-0326405-3) for the definition.

Theorem 3.5 of [Dykema - Interpolated free group factors](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102622631) (letting $A=L(\mathbb{Z})$ and $B=\mathbb{C}$) gives that $M_{2}(L(\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}))*L(\mathbb{Z}_{2})\cong M_{2}(L(\mathbb{F}_{3}))$. Is it known whether or not $L(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_{2})\cong L(\mathbb{Z})*L(\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ is a free group factor, or interpolated free group factor?

I am, of course, interested in related results like the one quoted above, as well, if the original question is still unknown. Please feel free to provide references as answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should just be a comment- but for some reason I couldn't add a comment.

It seems to me that using Corollary 5.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/funct-an/9211013.pdf) by Dykema, we indeed get a positive answer to your question.

Corollary 5.3 states that $L(G \ast H) \cong L(F(2-|G|^{-1}-|H|^{-1}))$, if $G$ and $H$ are nontrivial amenable groups, with $|G|+|H| \geq 5$.( $\infty ^{-1}=0$).

So $L(\mathbb Z \ast \mathbb Z_2)= L(F(1.5))$ according to the above formula (provided I subtracted correctly).

EDIT: I also found Theorem 1.1 in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102785073) to be very interesting. It relates to reduced $C^{\ast}$-algebras of free product groups.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Darth Vader!

Comment: I had JUST downloaded this paper of Dykema to have a look. Thanks for saving me the work.

Comment: @JonBannon you are very welcome. Thank you for accepting the answer :).

Comment: It seems I can comment now- even though I couldn't a few minutes ago :P. Nevertheless, I'm happy that the question got resolved.

Comment: @DarthVader, there's a reputation cut-off for commenting, so your upvotes are the reason you can now comment:  https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/comment .  (Also, I think that you can always comment on your own posts.)

Comment: @LSpice: Thank you- that probably explains it :).